# Model Change Event using controllerAs

Tags: angularjs

I've got a number of directives for a complex search form that are binding to the controller using the controllerAs syntax from Angular 1.3  Therefore there's no scope object, the model is set directly on the controller.

I want to bind to a change event, so that any time something is selected in one of the directives that changes the model in the controller, I can refresh the search list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us some of your work because it's a bit difficult to help you from nothing. To watch changes on a variable you can use :

```
$scope.$watch(MyVar, callBack, true);
```

You can also use two way binding by declaring a ng-model attribute on a form input, like so :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myVar" value=""/>
```

You can also do it in native javascript like that :

```
<input type="text" value="" onchange="javascript:myCallback();"/>
```

It seems to be a bit difficult in Angular to watch for a change on a value without playing with controller scope.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the actual code, it is difficult to say, but based on what I understand about your requirement, you can use ngChange directive to handle change in your model's value. More information on ngChange [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

If this is not what you are after, please update your question with some code so that we understand what your actual requirement is.